# Existence and uniqueness of the solution of a control system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, lipschitz-functions

Let $T>0$, $(U,d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{V}:=\{u:[0,T]\to U\,|\, u\text{ is measurable}\}$. Consider the control system $$\begin{cases}\dot{x}(t)=f(t,x(t),u(t)),\quad \text{a.e. }t\in[0,T],\\x(0)=x_0,\end{cases}$$
where $f:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n\times U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable.

According to [1, P. 102], for any $u\in\mathcal{V}$, the above control system has a unique solution $x:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ if the following conditions hold:

1. $U$ is a *separable* metric space.
2. There exist a constant $L>0$  and a modulus of continuity $\omega: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ such that

   2.1) $|f(t,x,u) - f(t,\hat{x},\hat{u})|\leq L|x-\hat{x}|+\omega(d(u,\hat{u})),\quad \forall t\in[0,T],x,\hat{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n,u,\hat{u}\in U,$

   2.2) $|f(t,0,u)|\leq L,\quad \forall (t,u)\in[0,T]\times U.$

My question is about the proof of this statement ([1] does not provide the proof).

Can one extend the standard Picard–Lindelöf theorem to prove it? specially, since condition 2.1 is basically a Lipschitz condition for $f$. I cannot also see what role separability of $U$ and the condition 2.2 play in the existence and uniqueness of the solution. Any help or hint with the proof is appreciated.

[1] *Yong, Jiongmin; Zhou, Xun Yu*, Stochastic controls. Hamiltonian systems and HJB equations, Applications of Mathematics. 43. New York, NY: Springer. xx, 438 p. (1999). [ZBL0943.93002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0943.93002).

Comment: I believe that separability is important because the problem is that $u$ is given to be a measurable, not necessarily continuous function. However, one can possibly approximate an arbitrary measurable $u$ by a continuous function $u$ in such a way that the solutions for the continuous approximations converge to that of the measurable function, and this approximation must use the fact that $U$ is separable.

Comment: Check out Lemma 2.6.2 and Theorem 54 from *Mathematical Control Theory: Deterministic Finite Dimensional Systems*, by E.D.Sontag.